# Action at pressing the key on certain line in jlist

Tags: java, key, line, action, jlist

I dont understand how to delete the line of JList wich is pressed by delete-key. I know that it sounds like "write for me the code please" but.... it is) Because i dont know is it possible to determine the actual line and then make it answer to my actions.

I started to write something like that

```
list.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        if(KeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()).equals("Delete")) {
             // removing    
        }

    }

});
```

but how to proceed i have no idea

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a [`DefaultListModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html) and assuming you want to delete all the selected items, the code you need is

```
list.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        if(KeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()).equals("Delete")) {
            // removing:
            DefaultListModel lm = (DefaultListModel) list.getModel();
            for(int i : list.getSelectedIndices()) {
                lm.remove(i);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

otherwise:

- if you don't want to remove all the selected items I didn't understand your question :(
- if you're not using a `DefaultListModel` you have to extend the JList class or (better) create your own implementation of [`ListModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ListModel.html) and create your own remove method...

Comment: Thanks! that's what i wanted

Comment: I cant(. My reputation is less than 15, thats why nobody can see my vote)